# Quadratic Reciprocity stated simply

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every now and then I like to take theorems that utilize specific notations and think of a way to say them to a layperson using only words they would understand.  After thinking about it a little for Quadratic Reciprocity, here's what I came up with:

"Let $p$ and $q$ be odd prime numbers that are different.  Then the statement '$p$ evenly divides $x^2-q$ for some whole number $x$ exactly when $q$ evenly divides $y^2-p$ for some whole number $y$', is true exactly when $p-1$ or $q-1$ is evenly divisible by $4$"

I just wanted to check to see if I got it right.

Comment: good enough for me

Comment: The statement does say that the simple relationship $(p/q)=(q/p)$ fails when $p$ and $q$ are both congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$, but it doesn't say exactly how it fails.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah interesting.  Does that make it weaker?  I feel like there would be only one way it could fail, and the Legendre symbol just represents it more neatly.